# How do you restrict keys on a Record type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How do you restrict keys on a Record/object?

In the example below, I want to see a ts error if the object you pass to a function contains a key or value present in my `DIMENSIONS` object.

I can make an error on a value, but nothing I've tried works on a key.

```js
const DIMENSIONS = {
  userType: 1,
  moduleVersion: 2
} as const;

type DimensionKeys = keyof typeof DIMENSIONS;
type DimensionValues = typeof DIMENSIONS[DimensionKeys];
type x = typeof DIMENSIONS;

function process<T extends string, V extends number>(yourDimensions: Record<Exclude<T, DimensionKeys>, Exclude<V,DimensionValues>>){
    return {...yourDimensions, ...DIMENSIONS};
}

// ----------------------------------------------
//             cool, go ahead
// ----------------------------------------------
const myCorrectDimensions = {
  country: 33
} as const;
const combinedDimensions = process(myCorrectDimensions);

// ----------------------------------------------
//        Na mate, that value is reserved
// ----------------------------------------------
const myInvalidValueDimensions = {
  country: 1
} as const;
const badDimensions = process(myInvalidValueDimensions);

// ----------------------------------------------
//        Na mate, that key is reserved
// ----------------------------------------------
const myInvalidKeyDimensions = {
  userType: 79
} as const;
const badDimensions2 = process(myInvalidKeyDimensions);
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wz753w) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: holy ****. @jcalz you legend.

Yes this is exactly right. Please do explain.

The line [K in typeof T] is particularly mystifying me.

How are you declaring a new generic inline??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach looks like this:

```
function process<T extends Record<keyof T, number>>(
  yourDimensions: { [K in keyof T]:
    K extends DimensionKeys ? never :
    T[K] extends DimensionValues ? never :
    T[K]
  }) {
  return { ...yourDimensions, ...DIMENSIONS };
```

Here we have a single objectlike [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` corresponding to the type of the function parameter `yourDimensions`.  It is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Record<keyof T, number>`, meaning it can have any keys at all, but its values must be assignable to `number`.

Then, the actual type of `yourDimensions` is the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `{[K in keyof T]: K extends DimensionKeys ? never : T[K] extends DimensionValues ? never : T[K]}`.  TypeScript will infer `T` to be the type of `yourDimensions`, but then check it against that mapped type.  For each key `K` from the keys of `T`, the accepted value type `K extends DimensionKeys ? never : T[K] extends DimensionValues ? never : T[K]` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that evaluates to to the input property type `T[K]` if and only if the input property does not use a key of `DimensionKeys` or a value of `DimensionValues`.  Otherwise it will be of type `never`, which is going to be an error (there are no values of type `never`).

Let's test it:

```
const example = process({
  a: 3, // okay
  b: 2, // error
  moduleVersion: 3 // error
})

/* function process<{
    a: 3;
    b: 2;
    moduleVersion: number;
}>(yourDimensions: {
    a: 3;
    b: never;
    moduleVersion: never;
}) */
```

Here the compiler infers `T` to be something like `{a: 3, b: 2, moduleVersion: number}`, so the type of the `yourDimensions` parameter is `{a: 3, b: never, moduleVersion: never}`.  But the input `{a: 3, b: 2, moduleVersion: 3}` doesn't match that type.  The `a` property is fine, but the other two cause errors because `2` and `3` are not of type `never`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=5.1.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgSQLIFEByBlBB5TMC8MA3gFAwwCuEApgE4AqAngA7UBcMAjADRkwC2IACYUANtQBqdCAEtwHAEwkAvjACGEGKEhQA3CRJQW1eDP7VIcsAGlqjTYQDWdkADMYR1m-jJ0WXBj6niZwZhay4BJqohTUDh7G3oiomDiYANqh5pbgtvYAukHGMAAeBAle7sl+aYEGrhRgwFBWMMy0IMBxEAA89DDUJVAWQpoAStSgtEI9zoze9NwwYBT8AEZ0AHybABR88xS0WeFWEBxEMOnWMDJgMHML+Wx85NeDw2CjptkRNnaaAH5ltQAG50GDPcjkehXfIDIYjTTHHJgKIxOIwIFgUHgyFQmHWfJ8ZQASmIfFo1CghzuFwAdAyDkcwiiIEsGXTqqkAjBlPplAYAPSCmAAWnFEslUulMtlctFJGFUOVKq0IBAoiWAHMQOoABbUNRCRUi+Vm80WkjaaACRgAYRAtEpzWRv3ipHIoEaUFojA4AGZ-Sp1JprXoreAbaB1rdqEJXadyu1Ot0dvx7Y7nVAE5GSfoTWKLUXixKC6qYGg1AI1MMllA9TWYCDorEbppKTRaGDjUqS33LWHbQgwM3RDIhGjYjnIOUPWrvb6OJxgxo1Tp9IO1kbp-Fk10IBA04xh6Px5PqDu80LTf3b7Ky6rK9Xax4G7A5m2YB26N2C3f-1KEY6EOI7ROOeQ7rOfBUHQTCsBwADsACcK6hpG4abtuLJugoSYdPuh7pieYFCBB2GnFeBiDoMaj8Mw4h4SmB47HOagBrw5BrIoHECMIYiSNIVgBioJJCgAVDADRNC04BtPh3Q9HO5BsTA-r6MqXEwAo6lQoIIjiFItC-BwKzrHQ-K7EyO7nC86gBjpnEmTitAObx+kCUZQnAmCLkiTZyoqWptmadiPmuXp-GGcZ3nmcGABk5LKpSRrgKIjCUJ2cHsFwrnJUIqXpRFBmCfIWn8jAYmCkAA)